# Handling File Upload Exception - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, exception

This is how i upload a file into my database but i am not able to handle my exception when the file uploaded is an invalid format or type.

I am able to handle exception when no file is uploaded but not when the file type is invalid or does not meet the standard.

How do i get this done please?

**Controller**

```
 public function import($id, Request $request)
    {


       $country= Country::all()->where('id',$id)->first();


           if($request->file('imported-file'))
           {
                     $path = $request->file('imported-file')->getRealPath();
                     $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader)
               {
                     })->get();

               if(!empty($data) && $data->count())
               {
                 foreach ($data->toArray() as $row)
                 {
                   if(!empty($row))
                   {
                     $dataArray[] =
                     [
                       'name' => $row['name'],

                     ];
                   }
    else {
            return redirect('admin')->with('error','File format Error');

         }
               }

               if(!empty($dataArray))
               {
                $country->teams()->createMany($dataArray);       
                 return redirect('admin')->with('status','Countries successfully added');

                }
              }
            }
else {
            return redirect('admin')->with('error','No file was uploaded');

         }

        }
```

Comment: what is an invalid type?

Comment: which file your uploading ?

Comment: @SapneshNaik, i upload excel files. So when user uploads a different format, i need to handle that exception

Comment: @kunal, i upload excel files

Comment: where do you do the file validation?

Comment: @madalinivascu, i don't actually know where the validation happens but when user inputs an invalid file format , i get an error like `"Undefined index: name"`

Comment: @pogba See my answer if it helps

Answer (score 1):

From [Laravel's documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-mimetypes), You can accept only a certain type of file using mime validation rule,

```
        'file' => 'required | mimes:application/vnd.ms-excel',
```

The mime-type `application/vnd.ms-excel` will match these file extensions `xls xlm xla xlc xlt xlw`

Answer (score 0):

I have uploading excel files in one of my project. Hope this will helps you:-

```
$file = Input::file('imported-file');
Excel::load($file ,function($reader){
                    $reader->each(function($sheet){
                        YourMOdelName::firstOrCreate($sheet->toArray());
                    });
                });
```

**YourModelName** is your table name suppose if table is users so you have to define **User** in that case.....
From this way you can get the extenstion of your uploading file:-

```
$ext= Input::file('imported-file')->getClientOriginalExtension();
echo $ext; //print the extension here
```

Hope it willl help!

Answer (score 0):

Okay i solved this in a very simple way by checking out the laravel documentation. So here is what i just added

```
if(($request->file('imported-file')->getClientOriginalExtension() != 'xls, xlm, xla ,xlc, xlt, xlw'))
        {

        }    
else {

   //process the file

}
```

Comment: How you can verify if it is excel or some other format?

Comment: ya now fine... i have also provide you this solution (y) see my answer @pogba